# CDI @Inject throws NullPointerException on Websphere 8.5

Tags: nullpointerexception, websphere, cdi, inject, throws

I've deployed an ear on websphere 8.5.

the application is composed of an ejb jar and a webapp ( Spring MVC ).

Here is my ejb :

```
    @Stateless
    public class DiscrepanciesServiceImpl implements DiscrepanciesService {

@Inject
private DiscrepancyDao discrepancyDao;

public DiscrepanciesServiceImpl(){};

public List<Discrepancy> viewDiscrepancies() {

            return discrepancyDao.findAll();
}
```

}

discrepancyDao is an interface that extends a generics interface as follows:

```
   public interface DiscrepancyDao extends _GenericDao<Discrepancy> {
```

}

implemented by DiscrepancyDaoImpl as follow:

```
        @Named("discrepancyDao")
        public class DiscrepancyDaoImpl extends _GenericDaoImpl<Discrepancy> implements  DiscrepancyDao {  }
```

and when I invoke viewDiscrepancies() i get nullpointerexception on discrepancyDao ( injected by CDI  )

I've deployed on WAS 8.5 and my empty beans.xml is in the META-INF folder.
During the deployment the was's console works fine with no errors.
Thanks in advance for your answers. 
Regards 
Fabio

Answer (score 1):

In a WAR, beans.xml goes in WEB-INF.

Comment: Are all of the classes in question in the EJB jar, or is one of them in the WAR? IIRC the Bean Archive setup in WAS is a little tricky and you'll probably need to include a beans.xml in both places to get everything to work.